# passing arguments to Model constructor

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can i pass my arguments to the model constructor,i have the following code in my controller

```
public  static function inbox(){

    $user=Sentry::getUser();
    $results=new Message($user->id);
    $inbox=$results->inbox();
    return $inbox;
}
```

And in my modal i am extending the parent modal constructor as follows

```
class Message extends \Eloquent {

private $user_id;

public function __construct($attributes = array())  {
    parent::__construct($attributes); // Eloquent
}}
```

now i want to pass the $user_id to the Message modal constructor,how do i achieve this

when inserting data to the db using the Eloquent create nothing is being inserted into the database here is the code

```
Message::create(
            array(
                'msg_id'=>$result->id,
                'subj'=>Input::get('subj'),
                'content'=>Input::get('content'),
                'sender_id'=>Input::get('sender_id'),
                'receivers_id'=>$user->id,
                'file'=>Input::get('file')

            )
        );
```

its like i have overidden built-in constructor of the Model class

Comment: Better rephrase this question and tell us what you want to achieve. I guess your code can be simplified greatly, since you're using Eloquent, but first describe the flow.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk is right. It seems like you are creating a new Message model, just to then call a mysterious function (`inbox`) on it. Eloquent Models usually belong to a database entity and are either created and saved or loaded from the db. It seems like you're using Message as some sort of repository though...

Answer (score 2):

You can use @PeterPopelyshko's approach and override the constructor or just use what Eloquent offers. [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment).

You can pass in attributes through your constructor by using an associative array:

```
$results = new Message(array(
    'user_id' => $user->id
));
```

Just make sure to define all the properties, you want to be *fillable* in the `$fillable` array in your model:

```
class Message extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('user_id');
}
```

*Note* that you don't need the `private $user_id` if this is a database field. Laravel handles them in it's own `$attributes` array.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Message extends \Eloquent {

private $user_id;

public function __construct($user_id, $attributes = array())  {
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    parent::__construct($attributes); // Eloquent

}}
```

and then you can use it in your controller

```
   $results=new Message($user->id);
```

and you can get access to $user_id within model like this `$this->user_id`

Comment: Tried your solution but it doesn't work when using model to insert data in the database

Comment: @Malouda question was about passing arguments to Model, not about database, so expand your question, or ask new one.

Comment: @Malouda Just remove `private $user_id` and saving to the db should work. Read my answer for a bit more info...

Comment: @lukasgeiter the $user_id is not a database column am using the $user_id for getting all messages the belong to the user with the $user_id

Comment: @Malouda Okay but what exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work when using model to insert data in the database". Maybe add that code to your question?